# JQuery - show/hide style attribute overriding css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I understand how CSS works in that the styling applied closest to the element overrides any previous styles.  My question is, how do the JQuery functions `show()` and `hide()` operate when there is a style attribute defined to a `<div>` tag like this:

`<div class='menuTab' style="display:block">`

For the sake of this example, assume that the css is something like:

```
div.menuTab{
    /* ..other css...*/
    display:none
}
```

Would applying the function `$('div.menuTab').hide()` change the style attribute of the menuTab HTML to `display:none`?

Comment: So just to check: `hide()` and `show()` work by inserting a style attribute into an HTML element with `display:none` or `display:block` (or whatever the previous display type was)?  They don't directly work with an external CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

In short: Yes.

`.hide()` is shorthand for:

```
.css("display","none");
```

So it will override your `display:block` inline style with `display:hidden`.

Unless `!important` is used, inline styles override CSS.

Comment: display:none or visibility:hidden

Comment: @mplungjan Cheers - `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

`$('div.menuTab').hide()` will result in `style="display:none"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

It will hide the class and override its property.

```
.hide()
```

is shorthand for:

```
.css("display","none");
```

It will override

```
 .css("display","block");
```

As you can see in inspect element of chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$('div.menuTab').hide();` js will change style in html literally as `display:none;`

Here you have an example. You can see the `.hide()` function changes the display from `block` to `none`.

http://jsfiddle.net/2tfuxzq5/3/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may easily find how `.hide()` works by checking [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js) (search for: `function showHide`).

jQuery `.hide()` and `.show()` are wrappers for `jQuery.css()` which change element's `style.display` property depending on its type (`.hide()` to `display = 'none'` and `.show()` to `'inline'`, `'block'` etc).